# How do I find all instances in Table 2, of a record in Table 1?

Tags: sql-server-2008

To start off, I'm using SQL server 2008 R2, and I've only been using it for 2 weeks with limited programming knowledge. What I need to do is find all instances of a record in Table 1 (t1), in Table 2 (t2), and output them to multiple tables (1 output table per t2.c1-c25). I'm currently doing this in dos using concatenate and find, but I know there must be a better way in SQL.

Here are the basic details of each table:

- t1 contains 1 column (t1.c1)
- t1.c1 has 100,000 records (rows)
- t2 has 25 columns
- t2 has 250,000 records (rows)

For example, record (row) 1 in t1.c1 is the word "dog", I would like to know where in t2.c1 the word "dog" appears, and output the entire record to t3 along with the keyword "dog". t3 would then look like this:

t3.c1 = dog
t3.c2-c28 = row with matching data
etc...

Eventually I would end up with t3 that contained all the matches in t2.c2 to t1.c1. This procedure would then be repeated to match t1.c1 to t2.c2, t1.c1 to t2.c3 upto t2.c25, each in it's own output table (t3-t28).

Any help would be appreciated, and I can clarify if there are any questions!

Comment: You can't have separate tables per output, really. How will the client know when the tables stop?

Comment: Technically I'm the client. The purpose of this is solely to generate a table per column where each key word is found. All the data in table 1 that is found in table 2 column 1 should be in it's own output table with the entire record. All data is fixed, in that there will never be any additions.

Comment: you can't have one table per match without a loop which is *not* what SQL is about

Answer (score 0):

It's a JOIN

```
SELECT
   t1.c1, t2.c2, ..., t2.c28
FROM
   t1
   JOIN
   t2 ON t2.c1 LIKE '%' + t1.c1 + '%'
```

Warnings:

- this will run badly (LIKE with leading wildcard)
- this matches if t1.c1 has 'rat' and t2.c1 has 'scratch'

It you expect an exact match then you'd have `ON t2.c1 = t1.c1` instead

If you want something to "number" the "virtual" tables then add this to the SELECT

```
DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY t1.c1) AS Virtualtable
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm actually looking for a LIKE not an exact. I'll give this a try! So searching for rat to find scratch is perfectly acceptable. The reasoning is that some of the data is user entered, and as such is susceptible is misspellings. In order to capture all variations, I'm going to have to do a LIKE (i.e., when searching for xentel, we also have zentel, zentell, xentell, so I search for "entel" and hope that captures all misspellings).

Comment: @Chetan: you should look at [DIFFERENCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188753.aspx): it may be useful here for you